# The best overloaded method match for int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments. What does this mean?

Tags: c#, parsing, methods, arguments, converters

Been trying for over 4 hours now, I'm no expert in the slightest I definitely need help with this. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
    // Declare variables 
    int inches = 0;
    double centimetres = 0;
    string input;

    //Ask for input
    Console.Write("Enter Number of centimetres to be converted: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    //Convert string to int
    centimetres = double.Parse(input);

    inches = int.Parse(input);

    inches = int.Parse(centimetres / 2.54);

    //Output result
    Console.WriteLine("Inches = " + inches + "inches.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The "conversion" `inches = int.Parse(centimetres / 2.54);` makes no sense. `int.Parse` is used to transform a `string` that represents a number into an `int`. But you pass it a `double`.

To make it work, your code would need to look like this:

```
//Ask for input
Console.Write("Enter Number of centimetres to be converted: ");
double input = Console.ReadLine();

//Convert string to int
double centimetres = double.Parse(input);

double inches = centimetres / 2.54;

//Output result
Console.WriteLine("Inches = " + inches + "inches.");
```

Some points:

1. Declare variables when used, not at the beginning of a method. This is a relict from old languages that required variables to be defined first.
2. Remove the `inches = int.Parse(input);` completely, because the result is never used as it is overwritten in the very next line.
3. Declare `inches` as `double` not as `int`. Otherwise you would be unable to have fractional inches.
4. Simply assign the result of the division to `inches`. There is no need for parsing here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most like this line:
inches = int.Parse(centimetres / 2.54);

int.Parse takes a string and centimetres / 2.54 is a double. to convert a double to an int use Convert.ToInt32 instead.

Comment: -1: You can't convert a `double` to a `string` using `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: In the original code inches is declared as as int, which is why I suggested using a function that takes a double and returns an int.

Comment: You said "to convert a double to a **string** use Convert.ToInt32 instead". I now realize that this could have been a simple typo, so if you correct it, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

the result of `centimetres / 2.54` is double, there is nor overload accept  double as parameter in [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)